# connect to mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

please excuse me for asking a primary question.  I need to connect to this link http://sunspares.millenniumit.com/phpmyadmin/ using c#.  It is of MySQL and i need to access a table called 'spares' in the 'inventory' database.  Can anyone help me to initialize this connection using C#. I found the below coding but i'm confused how to provide the exact server that i need to be connected  as well as to the table

```
con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```

Comment: What is `mysql_connect`? You need to add more of your code as that single line is meaningless.

Comment: Also is this php? you've tagged it as C#?

Comment: if your problem solved plz accept answer

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the [mysql connector/net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html).
2. Create a new project.
3. Add reference to: `MySql.Data`.
4. Add `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`.
5. Add the following code to your application:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
           string MyConString = @"SERVER=localhost;
               DATABASE=mydatabase;
               UID=testuser;
               PASSWORD=testpassword;";
           MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
           MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
           MySqlDataReader Reader;
           command.CommandText = "select * from mycustomers";
           connection.Open();
           Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
           while (Reader.Read())
           {
               string thisrow = "";
               for (int i= 0;i<Reader.FieldCount;i++)
                       thisrow+=Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",";
               listBox1.Items.Add(thisrow);
           }
           connection.Close();
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks.. i was able to connect to the database ..i found a tutorial ..and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;User      Id=root;pwd=;database=data1;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

-----------------------
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...
MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection();
Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
```